# Set embedded iframe src dynamically depending on variable in url

Tags: iframe

i would like to dynamically set the src of my iframe depending on a parameter in the Website-URL.

Examples:

- www.example.com?source=random

  The iframe should load `iframe 1`
- www.example.com?source=evenmorerandom

  The iframe should load `iframe 2`

Could someone help me with the correct code for that?
Thank you for your help!

Rob

Answer (score 0):

If  www.example.com is a PHP page:

```
<html><body>
    <?php print "<iframe src=' . $_GET["source"] . "'>"; ?>
</body></html>
```